# Mapping columns from different tables where one has multiple delimited values

Tags: join, dax, relationship, powerquery, lookup

I have two tables that I would like to map together, either using a join or relationship or a lookup (not sure which is most appropriate). In Table 1 I have a column that lists English words/slang and the different ways they are said across US, UK and Australian English separated by commas:

| Column1.words |
| --- |
| cigarettes, cigs, butts, f*gs, durry |
| tracksuit bottoms, tracksuits, sweatpants, trackies, dacks |

In Table 2, I have the categorisations of the words by US, UK and Australian:

| US_english | UK_english | AU_english |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cigs | f*gs | durry |
| candy | sweets | lollies |
| sweatpants | trackies | trackies |

I want to have a Column2 in Table 1 that pulls out a word from the list Column1 list (cigarettes, cigs...) based on the US_english table column in Table 2, so that my Table 1 then has two columns like this:

| Column1.words | Column2.matched |
| --- | --- |
| cigarettes, cigs, butts, durry | cigs |
| tracksuit bottoms, tracksuits, sweatpants, trackies, dacks | sweatpants |

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following **Calculated Column** added to *Table1*:

```
=
MINX (
    FILTER ( Table2, SEARCH ( Table2[US_english], Table1[Column1.words],, 0 ) > 0 ),
    Table2[US_english]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a 'Token Literal expected' error on the two commas in line 2. And when I remove the second comma: Expression.Error: The name 'MINX' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: are you using powerbi or powerquery ? PowerBI has the MINX operator, powequery does not

Comment: My bad, I was doing it in Power Query. It worked now. Thanks Jos!

Answer (score 1):

In M / Powerquery you could do

```
let x= Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Column2.matched", each Text.Combine(List.Select(Table2[US_english], (x) => Text.Contains([Column1.words], x)),",")) in x
```

[image]