# Cyclic reference error when doing Text.Combine in Power Query

Tags: join, dax, relationship, powerquery, lookup

I would like to do the equivalent of the below calculated column in Power BI as a Power Query expression.

The context to this is in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111791/mapping-columns-from-different-tables-where-one-has-multiple-delimited-values), but in short I basically want a new column in Table1 that checks if any of the words in Column1 (cigarettes, cigs, butts...) exist in a column in Table2 (US, UK, AU english) and it shows the value for the column I select (in this case US_english):

```
=
MINX (
    FILTER ( Table2, SEARCH ( Table2[US_english], Table1[Column1.words],, 0 ) > 0 ),
    Table2[US_english]
)
```

I have tried this but it gives me a Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation:

```
let x= Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Column2.matched", each Text.Combine(List.Select(Table2[US_english], (x) => Text.Contains([Column1.words], x)),",")) in x
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. Paste all of it into home..advanced editor...  It shows how to find words in one column from a column in another table. Click each of the step to see what it is doing

```
let  Source = #table({"Message"}, {{"How are you"}, {"It is a sunny day"},{"I love to eat kibble and bits"}}),
TableWithPhrases = Table.Buffer(#table({"Keyword"}, {{"day"}, {"night"}, {"sunny day"},{"kibble"}})),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Message", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Select(TableWithPhrases[Keyword], (x) => Text.Contains([Message], x)), ", "))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

(offhand I assume you are referencing Table1 within Table1 as your primary issue)

Comment: That worked. I need the Custom column in your code to reference Table2 though, as that contains the categories of the words that need to be filtered. Would I just change Table.Buffer(#table({"Keyword"}, to include Table2?

Comment: change the #table to reference your desired table and column TABLENAME[COLUMNAME]